# Check for 4 numbers before decimal and 1 number after decimal

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an input number field which should allow max 4 numbers before decimal and max 1 number after decimal or upto 6 numbers without decimal.
E.g. Valid 1.2, 113.5, 1234.5, 456789.

I used this RegEx `^\d{0,4}\.?(\.\d{0,1})?$` on keypress. It works fine, but gives false only after displaying the number like 113.55. How can I solve this?

My Keypress Function:

function OnKeyPress(e,DivID) {

```
            if ( e.which != 8 && e.which != 0  && e.which != 13 && e.which != 46 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
                        return false;
            }

            var val = j$('[id$='+DivID+']').val();


            if(DivID == 'ProximityCPPercentage')
            {
                var x = event.which || event.keyCode;
                if(val.indexOf('.') >= 0 && e.which == 46)
                    return false;
                else if(e.which == 46 && val.length == 3)
                    return false;
                if(val.indexOf('.') == 0)
                    val = '0' + val;
                if(e.which != 46)
                {                        
                    strval = val + String.fromCharCode(x);
                    var re = /^((.|0|[1-9]\d?)(\.\d{1})?|100(\.0?)?)$/;
                    if(!re.test(strval))
                        return false;
                }
            }              
            else if(val.indexOf('.') > 0)
            {
                if(e.which == 46 )
                    return false;
                var arra = val.split('.');
                var decval = arra[1];

                var val = arra[0];
                if(val.length > 6)
                    return false;
                if(decval.length > 0)
                    return false;                        
            }                
            else if(e.which != 46 )
            {
                if(val.length > 5)

                    return false;
            }

        }
```

Comment: Using two regexp's - `/^\d{0,4}[.]\d{0,1}$/` & `/\d{6}/` ?

Comment: `^\d{0,4}([.\d]\d)?$`

Comment: Is `.4` a valid value? And what about `4.`?

Comment: You need to define more precisely what patterns are accepted. Is "1." accepted? Is "123" accepted? Is ".3" accepted? Also, what exactly do you want to happen on keypress? Do you want to cancel/ignore a keypress which results in a non-matching pattern? Can you show us your keypress handling code? Have you considered using the `pattern` attribute on the input element?

Comment: The accepted values are 1,12,123,1234,12345,123456,0.1,1.1,12.1,123.1,1234.1. The text field should not allow to enter other than these.

Comment: Is there a way to check the regex before showing the value? Like after entering 123.4, if i try to enter 123.45 it should not show the '5' and return false. How to do this?

Comment: @Subha *Is there a way to check the regex before showing the value?* As I already mentioned in a previous comment, use the `pattern` attribute on the input element.

Comment: Instead of adding crucial information in a comment, edit your question to clarify it. For instance, the question still says "6 numbers without decimals", but now it seems you meant "up to 6 numbers without decimals"? Fix your question.

Answer (score 3):

Use following regex

```
^\d{0,4}([.\d]\d)?$
```

[Regex explanation here](https://regex101.com/r/fG1nD6/2)

[image: Regular expression visualization]

---

If you don't want to match 5 digits then use [negative look-ahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to avoid that

```
^(?!\d{5}$)\d{0,4}([.\d]\d)?$
```

[Regex explanation here](https://regex101.com/r/fG1nD6/4)

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: I think you meant `\.` instead of `.` in your `[]` section. So it should look like `^\d{0,4}([\.\d]\d)?$`

Comment: This matches `12345`.

Comment: +1 if you include a variation that invalidates `.4` and `4.`. It's unclear if the OP needs that, but others might.

Answer (score 2):

```
/^(?:\d{0,4}\.?(\d)|\d{0,6})?$/
```

**NOTE**: This also matches `.2` and `12345` and `''` (empty string). Based on your question, its not clear if you want to exclude those.

Explanation:

1. `^` Start the line.
2. `(?:` Start a "non-capturing group".
3. `\d{0,4}` Between 0 and four digits.
4. `\.?` Zero or one literal dots.
5. `(\d)` Capture one digit. (Do you want this captured?)
6. `|` OR
7. `\d{0,6}` Zero or Six digits.
8. `)` Closes our non-capturing group (number **2**).
9. `$` End the line.

### Tests:

```
var reg_exp = /^(?:\d{0,4}\.?(\d)|\d{0,6})?$/;
[
  '1.2',
  '113.5',
  '1234.5',
  '456789',
  '12345',
  '.2',
  '',
  '1234.',
  '113.55'
].forEach(c => {
  console.log('"' + c + '" tests to "' + reg_exp.test(c) + '"');
});

// "1.2" tests to "true"
// "113.5" tests to "true"
// "1234.5" tests to "true"
// "456789" tests to "true"
// "12345" tests to "true"
// ".2" tests to "true"
// "" tests to "true"
// "1234." tests to "false"
// "113.55" tests to "false"
```

Comment: It matches `12345` as well!

Comment: True, I assumed "or 6 numbers without decimal" meant "up to six decimals" but its possible they meant "six exactly". If so, its just a matter of changing the last `\d{0,6}` to `\d{6}`. Thanks for the comment though.

Comment: Your assumptions are wrong. It matches `1234.` too.